# Loading mysql rows from PHP into autocomplete jquery

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

```
<?php 
$cuvant = (isset($_GET['cuvant']) ? $_GET['cuvant'] : '');
// the word I want to get from the search box
$sql = "SELECT cuvant FROM cautare where cuvant like'".$cuvant."%'ORDER BY nr_cautari DESC limit 0,6";
// I search for that word in a table from database
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    var cuvinte=['<?php 
        $resursa = mysql_query($sql);
    ?>'];
    $( "#cautare" ).autocomplete({
        // #cautare is the id of the search box
        source: cuvinte
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to make an auto-completer with jQuery, and I have this code in the `index.php` page. I don't know how to fix this issue: When I try to search something on the page, nothing happens.

Comment: you need to do a [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) on your `$resursa`. note it is unsafe to directly inject your `$_GET['cuvant']` into your query. also, you are missing spaces after `like` and before `ORDER`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. If I use simple $cuvant=$_GET['cuvant'] I get an error undefined index...And now after I use isset I don't get the error any more but the word is not recieved from the search box.

Comment: using the ternary with `isset()` is fine, but you don't sanatize the value, ie. [`mysql_real_escape_string($cuvant)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: You need to fetch all your data first -> `$results=array(); $resursa = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resursa)){ $results[] = $row['cuvant'];} .... <script>... var cuvinte= <?php echo json_ecode($results); ?>...`

Comment: I understand what you are saying but to do all this stuff, first I need the word from the search box($_GET[''cuvant]) to search in the database. But I receive this error "Notice: Undefined index: cuvant in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 56" and if i put isset() I don't get this error but nothing happens.

Comment: What if the database changes after the page loads?  Without reloading the page the user will never get the new data.  You might want to look into using ajax and a separate .php script to perform the autocomplete lookup.

Comment: so you are not accessing this code with a url like - `?cuvant=....`? Where is `$_GET['cuvant']` coming from? are you trying to use your autocomplete to access your query?

Comment: $_GET['cuvant'] is coming from a text box used as a search box. And when I type something I want to store that in the $GET['cuvant'] and to search in the table from the database to see if the word matches and if matches to give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using jQuery Autocomplete: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I believe the variable that contains the values has to be valid JSON. Even doing an mysql_fetch_assoc() is going to return a php array that looks something like this for each row:

```
array(
  'cuvinte' => "something"
);
```

So, assuming that there are multiple rows returned from your query, I think you would need to do something like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var cuvinte= 
      <?php 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);    
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $resursa[] = $row['cuvant'];
        }
        echo json_encode($resursa);
    ?>;
    $( "#cautare" ).autocomplete({// #cautare is the id of the search box
      source: cuvinte
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Basically, this takes the result of your query, loops through all the rows, and builds a temporary array. The last step is to take that array and let PHP turn it into json for you.